# ItemDecoration overriding getItemOffsets() and animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I am applying equal margins to my `RecyclerView` using `GridLayoutManager` by overriding the `getItemOffsets()` method (see my code below).

However, when an Object is removed from the adapter the remove animation is called without the offsets. Thus, the anmiation starts at a different position than the object to be removed.

I tried to get the position via `getSpanIndex(position)` but the position (`parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)`) returns `NO_POSITION` since the object has already been removed from the adapter, when `getItemOffsets()` is called.

Is there any way to get the offsets in my case?

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, 
                     RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

    GridLayoutManager mgr = parent.getLayoutManager();
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

    if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
       // here I need to access the position of the current element
       // and call outRect.set(left, top , right, bottom);
       // which is not possible because it is no longer in the adapter
        return;
    } 

    int spanCount = mgr.getSpanCount();
    int spanSize = mgr.getSpanSizeLookup().getSpanSize(position);
    int spanIndex = mgr.getSpanSizeLookup().getSpanIndex(position, spanCount);

    if (spanIndex == spanCount-1) {
        // last element
        left = space / 2;
        right = space;
    } else if (spanIndex == 0) {
        // first element
        left = space;
        right = space / 2;
    } else {
        // middle element
        left = space / 2;
        right = space / 2;
    }
    outRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your problem when removing an item please? If you remove an element, the next elements animate to fill the empty position, how exactly does this not work?

Comment: For the elements in the RecyclerView the offsets are shown correctly (e.g. 20 pixels left and 40 pixels right for an element in the last column). With the  code above the animation starts at a position without margins (0 left and 0 right) since I return from the method due to `position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION`. Here I need to figure out the position of the deleted element (e.g. last column) to apply the correct offsets for a smooth animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the views `LayoutParams`. If you don't use some custom `LayoutManager`, it should contain the information you need.

```
int position = ((RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).getViewAdapterPosition();
```

Comment: Many thanks for `LayoutParams`! `getViewAdapterPosition()` did not work somehow but now I am using `RecyclerView.LayoutParams.leftMargin` etc. to apply margins instead of calling `outRect.set(left, top, right, bottom)` and the animation is smooth as expected!

Comment: @jeff_bordon can you explain how you managed to do it. I get the idea, but still have the problem that the margin (or offset) is really applied to the wrong item - not the currently removed one, but the next, which is still in the adapter.

Comment: please note that adapterPosition might be different than Recycler one if it's pass before "change" animation

Answer (score 5):

Actually, It's not good decision to get child position from parent. Actual state of view can be different to real state, 'cause at the same time is working or ItemDecorator, or LayoutManager, or RecyclerView to rule them,or Adapter to change position of some elements.

Better way, when ask Recycler to give you ViewHolder for certain view. Then you can get whole information what you need (getLayoutPosition(), getAdapterPosition()).

```
parent.getChildViewHolder(view).getLayoutPosition();
parent.getChildViewHolder(view).getAdapterPosition;
```

And another advise, not from your case. If you need to get ItemCount, don’t use adapter.getItemCount(), better is get from state, because count of items can be different in Adapter and Recycler.

```
state.getItemCount()
```

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across this same issue here and I've read the answers and discussions. This maybe a really late answer but I'd answer for the sake of others experiencing this issue.

The answer of Julian Os should have been marked as the correct answer but did not really explained much.

Here's the detailed explaination:

on the `ItemDecoration`'s `getItemOffsets()` first get the item position 
`parent.getChildViewHolder(view).getAdapterPosition();` as ilyagorbunov has noted this is a safer way of getting the view's position. This method return's `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` when the queried view no longer exist. So if that's the case go check for the `parent.getChildViewHolder(view).getOldPosition()` which returns the old position of an animating view. This method also return's `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` when the ChildViewHolder is no longer present in the view or has completed the animation.

If you are having multiple view type in your adapter, just directly get the view type from `parent.getChildViewHolder(view).getItemViewType()`

For Completeness here's some code snippet:

```
override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect?, view: View?, parent: RecyclerView?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
    var position = parent?.getChildViewHolder(view)?.adapterPosition
    if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        val oldPosition = parent?.getChildViewHolder(view)?.oldPosition
        if (oldPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return
        position = oldPosition
    }

    val viewType = parent?.getChildViewHolder(view)?.itemViewType

    when (viewType) {
        //do your outRect here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So after trying to figure this out for some time, I eventually stumbled across `ViewHolder#getOldPosition`.

The javadoc says the following:

> When LayoutManager supports animations, RecyclerView tracks 3 positions for ViewHolders to perform animations.
>
> If a ViewHolder was laid out in the previous onLayout call, old position will keep its adapter index in the previous layout.

In other words, getOldPosition() returns the ViewHolder's adapter position that It was located at before it got removed.

So to get this value from inside your ItemDecoration#getItemOffsets method, simply state:

```
parent.getChildViewHolder(view).getOldPosition()
```

I tested it myself, and it does indeed work :).

Answer (score 0):

you should get you spanIndex from
 `(view.layoutParams as?GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams)?.spanIndex`

and same for spanSize

`(view.layoutParams as? GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams)?.spanSize`

thanks to that you are safe during animation where adapter might have new set of data and `SpanSizeLookup` will work on different set of items then those you are calculating offsets for

using adapter within item decorator is not good idea. try always to do all calculation based only on view and recycler state. You might consider passing some data via tags in view or resources within recycler state.